# $E,F$ normed spaces. Linear $T:E\rightarrow F$ bounded iff $T^\dashv(\{y\in F:\parallel y\parallel\le 1\})$ has nonempty interior.

Tags: vector-spaces, normed-spaces

I want to prove the following

> Let $E,F$ be normed spaces and $T:E\rightarrow F$  linear map. Then, $T$ is bounded iff $T^\dashv(\{y\in F:\parallel y\parallel\le 1\})$ has nonempty interior.

**My attempt:** Suppose $T$ is bounded. Then, it is continuous, meaning that $T^\dashv(\{y\in F:\parallel y\parallel\le 1\})$ is closed *(and?...)*

I have been unable to relate the fact that the interior is not empty with the rest. Any hints?

Comment: What is $T^\dashv$?

Comment: @UmbertoP. Pre-image

Comment: The best way to write that is $T^{-1}$.

Comment: Allow me to desagree. Actually, I've seen it done in a book and started using this notation: I think it is clearer. There is no need to use the same notation for inverse and preimage!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose the inverse image has empty interior. Then for every $n >0$,
it does not contain an open ball of radius $1/n$ around $0$ in $E$. This implies that for every $n$ there is $x_n\in E$ such that $||x_n||<\frac{1}{n}$ but $||T(x_n)||>1$. In particular, $T$ is not continuous at zero, so $T$ is not bounded.

For the other direction, if the inverse image has non-empty interior, then there is some point $p\in T^{-1}\{x\in F: ||x||\leq 1\}$ such that for some $\delta>0$ there is a ball $B_{\delta}(p)$ of radius $\delta$ around $p$ in $E$ whose image is contained in the unit ball of $F$. This implies that whenever $||x-p||<\delta$ in $E$, $||Tx||\leq 1$ in $F$. In particular, for every $x\in E$, ($x\neq p$),
the vector $(x-p)\frac{\delta}{2||x-p||}$ belongs to $B_{\delta}(p)$ and so
$$||T(x-p)\frac{\delta}{2||x-p||}||\leq 1$$
By linearity:
$$||T(x-p)|||\leq ||x-p||\frac{2}{\delta}$$
and so $T$ is continuous at the point $p$. It follows from linearity that $T$ is continuous everywhere, because if $x_n$ is a sequence in $E$ converging to some $x_0\in E$, then $x_n-x_0+p$ converges to $p$, and so $T(x_n-x_0+p)$ converges to $T(p)$, which implies that $T(x_n-x_0)$ converges to zero, as required.

Comment: Your answer is correct, of course, but going from definitions the ball of radius $\delta$ is not necessarily centered at the origin but at some point of $E$.

Comment: @UmbertoP. - Thank your for your comment, I've corrected my answer.